# do memset or bzero guarantee that a field pointer in a struct will be nulled out?

Tags: c++, pointers, memset

Suppose you have a C++ class Foo, and you say:

```
Foo* foos = new Foo[SOME_CONSTANT];
memset(foos, 0, sizeof(Foo)*SOME_CONSTANT);
//or the bzero equivalent
```

and that Foo has a data member `Bar* barPtr`. Will the above operation guarantee that 
barPtr will be NULL? (i.e. zero). I ran into a case in gdb where this didn't hold for memset and I'm curious why.

I know the above is probably bad practice but I'm asking for curiosity.

I realized that I had an extra *, i was doing sizeof(Foo*)*SOME_CONSTANT in the memset...

Comment: There seems to be some confusion as to what you're asking. `memset` should ensure `barPtr` is set to zeros, which is not necessarily `NULL`. What value did you see for `barPtr`?

Comment: `memset()` will set the target to all-bits-zero. This will *typically* set pointers to null, but the language doesn't require a null pointer to be represented as all-bits-zero. But I'm surprised by your "case in gdb where this didn't hold for memset"; I'm not aware of any system that supports gdb where null pointers *aren't* all-bits-zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the one hand, it is implementation-defined. `memset` or `bzero` will fill the pointer value with all-zero bit pattern, which is not guaranteed to be a physical representation of null pointer on the given platform. It is not even guaranteed to produce a valid pointer value, meaning that you might end up with so called *trap representation*, which triggers undefined behavior when accessed.

On the other hand, `bzero` is (or used to be) a part of POSIX specification. If memory serves, POSIX requires (or at least used to require) null-pointers to be represented by all-zero bit pattern, meaning that on POSIX systems it will indeed set a pointer to null.

But again, the guarantee given by POSIX is just an example of an  implementation-specific property mentioned in the first part of my answer. The language (C or C++) provides no such guarantees.

Answer (score 3):

No. The representation of the null pointer is not required to be all bits zero.

See [section 5](http://www.c-faq.com/null/index.html) and [question 7.31](http://www.c-faq.com/malloc/calloc.html) of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: @James, I think it is. See the FAQ I've added to my answer.

Comment: @aleguna, no it is not. See the FAQ. Writing `p=0` does not set all bits of `p` to zero if `p` is a pointer.

Comment: The questions isn't about NULL, he's asking why his memset call isn't zeroing the members of the class

Comment: @lhf, the first line of the question says class

Comment: @aleguna: `NULL` in C can be defined as *constant* integer zero, not just any zero. I.e. such `NULL` must be a compile-time zero, immediately recognizable as zero by the compiler. Whether such zero by itself is "all-bits zero" or is completely irrelevant, since its representation can change entirely once it is converted to pointer type. Meanwhile, if `NULL` in C is defined as `(void *) 0` you can no longer claim that it is "all bits zero". `(void *) 0` can easily stand for `0xBAADFOOD` physically.